# Java: How to Delete the first occurrence of matching substring between 2 strings?

Tags: java, regex

If I have two strings ..
say

```
string1="Hello dear c'Lint and dear Bob"
```

and

```
string2="dear"
```

I want to **Compare the strings** and **delete** the first occurrence of  matching substring .. 
*the result of the above string pairs is:*

`Hello c'Lint and dear Bob`

This is the code I have written which takes input and returns the matching occurence:

```
System.out.println("Enter your regex: ");
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String RegEx = bufferRead.readLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(RegEx);
System.out.println("Enter input string to search: ");
bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bufferRead.readLine());

boolean found = false;
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("I found the text:\"" + matcher.group() +
            "\" starting at index \'" +
            matcher.start() + 
            "\' and ending at index \'" + 
            matcher.end() + 
            "\'");
}
```

Comment: So `string1.replaceFirst(string2, "");` would not do what you want?

Comment: @assylias: Please see the comments to flup's answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could *either* use:

```
string result = string1.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(string2), "");
```

Or you could avoid regexes entirely:

```
int index = string1.indexOf(string2);
if (index == -1)
{
    // Not found. What do you want to do?
}
else
{
    String result = string1.substring(0, index) + 
                    string1.substring(index + string2.length());
}
```

You can report the region here using `index` and `string2.length()` very easily. Of course if you *want* to be able to match regular expression patterns, you should use them.

EDIT: As noted in another answer, both of these will remove `"dear"` from `"and_dear_Bob"` leaving `"and__Bob"` - with the underscores representing spaces. So you'll end up with two spaces between words. And it doesn't force the match to be a whole word, either. It does exactly what you described, but it doesn't give you the result you apparently want.

**Edit:**
First choice of code outputs: `Hello c'Lint and dear Bob`
where Hello and c'Lint have two whitespace character in the middle. 
While this code:

```
string result = string1.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(string2+" "), ""));
```

gets rid of additional whitespace character.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will accept it after 4mins :) It feels great to go through your suggestions ^.^

Comment: +1 -Jon @InfantPro'Aravind' only feels great? No up-vote feeling or stuff?

Comment: `Pattern.quote()` takes just one argument, Shouldn't this be `String result = string1.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(string2),"");`

Comment: @AvinashNair, even I thought the same And edited the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: @joeyrohan, I was upto some R&D, You should be knowing this, that SO doesn't allow to accept answer for 10/15 mins immediately after posting question.